# SSRS 2008 limiting scope based on expression

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a fairly simple problem, but I don't think I understand SSRS and scopes well enough to figure this out.

What I have is a case (one entity) that can have multiple appointments (another entity). Appointments have a date and a status. I want to display the next soonest appointment date and its status. To display the date I'm using

```
=Min(IIf(Fields!appt_start.Value > Globals!ExecutionTime, Fields!appt_start.Value, Nothing))
```

The idea is that I first pick only those appointments that occur in the future, and then grab the soonest one. It seems to work great.

Now, I need to apply the same filtering logic, but display the appointment status rather than the date. From my understanding, this is where scopes would come in. I could limit my scope to just the appointment I want, and then show its status. But I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this particular problem would be to use a filter in combination with the First function. Add a filter to the table to only show dates greater than the current day. Use a table row with no grouping and use expressions like this:

```
=First(Fields!appt_start.Value)
=First(Fields!appt_status.Value)
```

Another option would be to add calculated fields to the dataset to only populate values such as status when the date is greater than the current day. This is useful if you need to show more information later on.

**Edit:** Yes, you would want to sort the data by date for the First function to work right. You can actually filter at 3 different levels in SSRS. Right-click on your dataset and go to Dataset Properties. Click on Filters. Click Add. Fill in the expression, operator, and value to meet your need. You can also do this in the group properties or the table properties.

Comment: The filtering part is what I'm unsure of how to do. Also, wouldn't I need to sort the dataset by ascending order on appt_date before I could use First()? My data may contain many appointments in the future, in any order.

Comment: I may need all appointments for other fields in the report. For example, I want to show how many appointments a case has in total, including ones in the past. What would be the best approach? Should I create two identical datasets, one with filters for the next appt data/status and another one without? Or is there a better way?

Comment: In that case I would just put a filter on a specific table or group. No need to duplicate datasets.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I'll see if I can get a group filter working without altering how the report looks. If worst comes to worst I can create another dataset and get it working that way.